# android black screen when back button is pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I would like to avoid the black screen between activities when the back button is pressed.

If I kill an activity with killProcess I obtain the same result.

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

I would prefer not to have to use AsyncTask. I call the activity through an intent in an activityforresult.

Comment: 1. you could call `finish()` on your `Activities` that you are done with,instead of killing. 2. What do you mean by black screen? I have never experienced such a thing.

Comment: With finish() I don't return to my preview Activity. The black screen means that while back button is pressed and the new activity is loaded appears a black screen, it doesn't last more than a seconds but it is annoying.

Comment: Probably this is happening on your emulator only. Have you experienced the same on a real device?

Comment: @Álvaro I have not experienced this black screen either. Maybe it is your activity taking a second to load.

Comment: I haven't tested it on a real device. I think maybe the problem is when is loading the second activity, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The black screen is usually sign that the layout is not yet initialized. traceview your app to see the time it takes before each layout load.**

In other terms your activity is still trying to load the layout. Depending on the hierarchy and complexity it can take a lot of time especially if you have processing stuff before you set the content view or initialize the views.

i am 100 sure that there is your issue.

**use async tasks to properly handle loading and processing tasks.**

**Use finish and never kill tasks manually. the activity has a lifecycle which should be followed.**

Comment: I think the problem maybe is the loading of the layout, I have just seen the traceview. I also will change the kill tasks manually for the finish(), it's cleaner, thanks.